# Como mover mi personaje basándome en donde mira la cámara?

Tags: c++, ogre

estoy trasladando un cuerpo rígido de bulleet basándome el la dirección derivada de la cámara de Ogre. Uso el wrapper OgreBullet.

```
Ogre::Vector3 dir = _camera->_getDerivatedDirection();
myRigid->getBulletRigidBody()->translate(dir.x, dir.y, dir.z);
```

Pero solo se mueve para adelante, o sea que si miro para la derecha se desplaza para adelante sin tener en cuenta la dirección de la cámara.

En que le estoy errando?